# Disposing the result of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In a code like this which is used to check for existence of an object based on a condition,
how do I dispose query collection after the count is checked.

```
 var query = from p in someContext
             where (p.Name == Name && p.Status == true)
             select p;

 if (query.Count() > 0)
    return true;
 else
    return false;
```

This is a simple scenario but there can be a situation where the query can result in a huge collection.
So my question is in a cases where the requirement is to just check for existence of an object, how can
this query be written so that the result collection is not in the memory after the check for count is done.

Regards.

Comment: Not really an answer but you could reduce the size of the query by doing this
 var query = from p in someContext
             where (p.Name == Name && p.Status == true)
             select p.Name;

and replace query.Count() with query.Any()

Comment: After returning from your function `query` gets out of scope and garbage collector will do the work for you.

Comment: What query provider are you using? This query shouldn't need to create any collection if you're using an ORM. If it's an in-memory collection you should be able to clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the LINQ extension method `.Count()` actually does is dependent on the query provider used.  In the case of Entity Framework (assuming that's what you're using), a SQL query will be generated that will return the record count, not the records themselves.  Thus, you do not need to worry about disposing of a large collection.

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        using( var db = new TestContext() )
        {
            db.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;

            var query = from mfg in db.Manufacturers
                        where mfg.Name.Contains( "Inc." )
                        select mfg;

            var count = query.Count();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Generates SQL:

```
select
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].Manufacturers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Name] LIKE N'%Inc.%'
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```